# Shiny display months in sliderInput and predefine vectors

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, shiny

I'm currently trying to code a Shiny-App and close to solution, I want to reach. However, there are some issues, that I'm not able to solve...

```
if(!require(shiny)){
  install.packages("shiny")
  require(shiny)
}

if(!require(tidyverse)){
install.packages("tidyverse")
require(tidyverse)
}

if(!require(readxl)){
  install.packages("readxl")
  require(readxl)
}

if(!require(lubridate)){
  install.packages("lubridate")
  require(lubridate)
}

prodpromonat <- tibble(prodmonat = c("2008-01-01", "2008-02-01", "2008-03-01", "2008-04-01", "2008-05-01", "2008-06-01", "2008-07-01", "2008-08-01"),
                   n = c("3216", "3268", "2398", "2987", "4003", "3103", "3064", "2786"))

prodpromonat$prodmonat <- as.Date(prodpromonat$prodmonat)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        "zeitraum",
        "Produktionszeitraum",
        min = min(prodpromonat$prodmonat),
        max = max(prodpromonat$prodmonat),
        value = c(max(prodpromonat$prodmonat)-90, max(prodpromonat$prodmonat))
  ),

    fluidRow(
      radioButtons(
        "farbschema",
        "Farbschema",
        choices = c("Einfarbig", "Zweifarbig"),
        selected = "Einfarbig"
      )
    ),

    fluidRow(
      uiOutput("farbwahl")
    )
    ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        title = "Produktionsmenge" ,
        plotOutput(
          outputId = "produktionsmenge"
        )
      )
  )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  farbeninput <- reactive({
    switch(input$farbschema,
       "Zweifarbig" = c(input$farbe1, input$farbe2),
       "Einfarbig" = c(input$farbe1, input$farbe1)
    )
  })

  filter_produktionsmenge <- reactive({
    min <- filter(prodpromonat, prodmonat >= floor_date(input$zeitraum[1], "month"))
    max <- filter(prodpromonat, prodmonat <= floor_date(input$zeitraum[2], "month"))
    semi_join(min, max, by = "prodmonat")
  })

  output$farbwahl <- renderUI({
    switch(input$farbschema,
       "Zweifarbig" = tagList(textInput("farbe1", "Farbe 1", value = "#808080"), textInput("farbe2", "Farbe 2", value = "#1E90FF")),
       "Einfarbig" = textInput("farbe1", "Farbe", value = "#808080")
       )
  })

  output$produktionsmenge <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filter_produktionsmenge(), aes(factor(prodmonat), n)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = factor(as.numeric(month(prodmonat) %% 2 == 0)))) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=rep(farbeninput())) +
      xlab("Produktionsmonat") +
      ylab("Anzahl produzierter Karosserien") + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") 
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Issue #1: In the sliderInput i provide every single day within the selected timespan, whereas i only want to provide only the existing months, preferably without giving any hint for the day. Every solution i tried to just print "%Y-%m" produces an error, so i sticked to the days...

Issue #2: Is there any possibility to define a color-vector before using the uiOutput? Right now it does almost work as i planned, but there is an error shown before the rendered UI is finished rendering and shown in the sidebar. My guess is, that the vector is not existing until the renderUI is finished, as the error reads "Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 0 provided.". So i'd like to initialise it. Same is valid for changing to the two-color mode for the first time.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve those issues? Thanks alot!

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

Found solutions to issues before. However, issues #1 and #2 still exist.

*edit: removed a bracket from the code

Comment: First, I have no idea about date problem. I've tried some hacks with `as.yearmon()` from `zoo` package but without any success. Second, I would suggest some submitt button with the setting because `textInput()` is not inicialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue #1:

Add `timeFormat = "%Y-%m"` to the sliderInput (already answered by waskuf)

### Issue #2:

The problem stems from some dependency issue:

- `renderPlot` is depending on `farbeninput` and `filter_produktionsmenge`. The plot will be rendered every time when:

  - `farbeninput` changes,
  - The sliders are modified, thus the data is recalculated via `filter_produktionsmenge`.

If you add print statements to every block you can see that `renderPlot` is called twice because `farbeninput` changes twice.

```
[1] "renderUI"
[1] "renderPlot"
[1] "farbeninput"
[1] "renderPlot"
[1] "farbeninput"
[1] "filter_produkt"
```

### Why is this happening?

`farbeninput` is dependent of `input$farbschema`, `input$farbe1` and `input$farbe2`. This means that if any of those inputs change, `farbeninput` will be recalculated.

When changing `input$farbschema` `farbeninput` is rendered twice:

1. Because `input$farbschema` changed.
2. When the `textInput`s are rendered in the UI.

This is what caused the warnings shown!

### Solution

You need to make `farbeninput` so that it is only calculated after the `textInput`s have been rendered. You can achieve this using `req`.

For example: If the value of `input$farbschema` is `"Zweifarbig"`, and either `input$farbe1` or `input$farbe2` is not rendered a `NULL` value is returned. If both are rendered then `c(input$farbe1, input$farbe2)` is returned as normal.

```
farbeninput <- reactive({
  switch(input$farbschema,
         "Zweifarbig" = {
           req(input$farbe1)
           req(input$farbe2)
           c(input$farbe1, input$farbe2)
         },
         "Einfarbig" = {
           req(input$farbe1)
           c(input$farbe1, input$farbe1)
         }
  )
})
```

Add `req(farbeninput())` to `renderPlot` to avoid rendering when `farbeninput` is `NULL`:

```
output$produktionsmenge <- renderPlot({
  req(farbeninput())
  ggplot(filter_produktionsmenge(), aes(factor(prodmonat), n)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = factor(as.numeric(month(prodmonat) %% 2 == 0)))) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=rep(farbeninput())) +
    xlab("Produktionsmonat") +
    ylab("Anzahl produzierter Karosserien") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For issue #1, you just have to add the timeFormat argument to your sliderInput, like this

```
sliderInput(
    "zeitraum",
    "Produktionszeitraum",
    min = min(prodpromonat$prodmonat),
    max = max(prodpromonat$prodmonat),
    timeFormat = "%Y-%m",
    value = c(max(prodpromonat$prodmonat)-90, max(prodpromonat$prodmonat))
  ),
```